Firestore .get() Method Times Out in Firebase Function Despite High Resources
I'm encountering an issue with a Firebase Cloud Function that is intended to read a list of task IDs from Firestore and return them. Despite the Firestore document being small and increasing the function's resources, the function consistently times out when attempting to fetch the document using the .get() or .stream() method. Below is the function's code:

from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, initialize_app
from firebase_functions import https_fn, logger

app = initialize_app()

@https_fn.on_call()
def list_tasks(request: https_fn.CallableRequest):

    if request.auth is None:
        return []

    db = firestore.client()
    
    user_doc_ref = db.collection(f'users').document(request.auth.uid)
    logger.log(f'{user_doc_ref = }')
    
    user_doc = user_doc_ref.get() # The problem is here!
    logger.log(f'{user_doc = }')
    if user_doc.exists:
        task_ids = user_doc.to_dict().get('task_ids', [])
        logger.log(f'{task_ids = }')
        return task_ids
    else:
        return []


Few milliseconds after the function is called, it logs the user_doc_ref =  correctly but times out without logging user_doc = . The only log I get before the timeout is:
NOTICE 2024-04-01T16:05:40.512879Z user_doc_ref = <google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at 0x3eaaf4a68b50>

Could someone help identify what I might be missing or suggest why the Firestore function interactions are experiencing such significant delays? Are Firebase functions interacting with Firestore inherently slow, or could there be another issue that I'm missing?
Here are some additional details:
The Firestore user document is very small, with less than 10 fields (mostly strings and numbers), and one of the fields is task_ids, a list of strings.
There is only one user in Firestore! and that user has the right uid!
I've increased the function's resources to 8 CPUs and 4GB of memory and set the timeout to 300 seconds, but the issue persists.
My Firestore security rules are set to allow read and write for all documents:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}


most likely async issue. you need to await the result.

@RonnieRoyston: the default Python SDK has synchronous calls. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#python_4 for an example of that. To get async API calls, you can import firestore_async (see here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#python_2), but OP doesn't seem to be doing that.

Thanks RonnieRoyston and @FrankvanPuffelen for your swift responses. I initially doubted the issue was related to asynchronous operations, but there have been some developments.
After posting my query, I went to bed and, to my surprise, the next day the same code started working perfectly without any modifications. I even rolled back most of my changes and adjusted the rules, yet everything continued to function seamlessly until I introduced a new function designed to generate new tasks.
Here’s the critical line from that function:

db.collection(f'users').document(request.auth.uid).update({'task_ids': firestore.ArrayUnion([task_id])})

Before implementing this line, all operations were smooth. However, once it was executed, another function tasked with reading the task_id started to time out once more. I'm beginning to wonder if the issue might be related to how Firestore manages the db=firestore.Client() connections. Perhaps keeping the connection alive for reuse, and when multiple functions access Firestore with a few seconds of eachother, it somehow conflates these db instances?
I’ve structured these functions carefully, ensuring they are not called simultaneously.

@https_fn.on_call()
def list_tasks(request: https_fn.CallableRequest):
    # In this function I get a timeout on db.--anything--.get() 
    return task_service.list_tasks(request, firestore.client(app))

@https_fn.on_call()
def create_task(request: https_fn.CallableRequest):
    # in this function I call db.collection(f'users').document(request.auth.uid).update({'task_ids': firestore.ArrayUnion([task_id])}) 
    return task_service.create_task(request, firestore.client(app))


Hey @Ali. Good to hear that you made progress on the issue  It's pretty hard to digest the update in comments though. So: if the problem still persists, please edit your question to describe the current problem. If the problem is gone now, I vote to close the question as not reproducable/ephemeral.
